# Can't save entity because of null version column. NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, concurrency

I have a quite straight mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="XXXX.DomainLayer" namespace="XXXX.DomainLayer.Entities">
    <class name="Project" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="Id" column="ProjectID" unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
            <generator class="guid.comb" />
        </id>
        <version name="Version" generated="always" type="BinaryBlob" />
    <!-- poperties -->
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And corresponding entity looks like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity<T> where T : AbstractEntity<T> {
    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual Byte[] Version { get; set; }

    // other properties, methods
}
public class Project : AbstractEntity<Project>, IAggregateRoot {
    // specific properties, methods
}
```

I exported a schema to `SqlServer`. Everything's fine there. But each time I post a form (`create action`) `SqlServer` throws an exception which states:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Version', ...

So `insert` gets reverted.

**INITIAL PROBLEM IS SOLVED**

The actual problem is that I cant make edit over an entity - I'm getting `StaleObjectStateException`.

> Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) [XXXX.DomainLayer.Entities.Project#707991d0-07b5-45fc-99ed-a0cc00db108a]

When checking in the `SQLServer` it is clear that Version column stays null no matter what.

**Controller code**

```
public ActionResult Create() {
    return View("Edit", new EditProjectViewModel());
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id) {
    var project = this.repo.Get(id);
    var model = Mapper.Map<Project, EditProjectViewModel>(project);

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(EditProjectViewModel model) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {

       model.InitiatedBy = this.userService.GetUser(some_param);
       model.ProblemContext = BBCode.ToHtml(model.ProblemContext);

       var project = Mapper.Map<EditProjectViewModel, Project>(model);

       if(project.IsTransient) {
           this.repo.Add(project);
       }
       else {
           try {
               this.repo.Update(project);
           }
           catch(NHibernate.StaleObjectStateException e) {
               // Some logic here
           }
       }

       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });
   } // if(ModelState.IsValid) {
   return View(model);
}
```

Where repository `Update` method looks like:

```
public void Update(T entity) {
    using(var tx = this.session.BeginTransaction()) {
        /* try { */
            this.session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
            tx.Commit();
        /* }
        catch(StaleObjectStateException) {
            try {
                entity = this.session.Merge(entity);
                tx.Commit();
            }
            catch(Exception) {
                tx.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
        */
    }
}
```

**DI piece**

```
public class DataAccessModule : NinjectModule {
    public override void Load() {
        this.Bind<ISessionFactory>()
            .ToMethod(c => new Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory())
            .InSingletonScope();

        this.Bind<ISession>()
            .ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.TryGet<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
            .InRequestScope();

        this.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>))
            .InRequestScope();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting "sql-type" to "timestamp" and "unsaved-value" to "null" (see my answer)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add sql-type="timestamp" to version column mapping. E.g.

```
<version name="Version" generated="always" unsaved-value="null" type="BinaryBlob">
    <column name="Version" not-null="false" sql-type="timestamp"/>
</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using correct type for `<version>`?

From [NHibernate documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-version):

> Version numbers may be of type Int64, Int32, Int16, Ticks, Timestamp,
>   or TimeSpan (or their nullable counterparts in .NET 2.0).

Comment: Found it in Benjamin Perkins' book `http://www.amazon.com/Working-NHibernate-Wrox-Blox-ebook/dp/B005UQLK6W/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1347539632&sr=8-2&keywords=working+with+nhibernate+3.0 (page 174)

Comment: I see... Not sure what's the problem then. Maybe you could try with some other type?

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally found a solution which is quite obvious:

```
<id name="Id" column="ProjectID" unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
        <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <version name="Version" generated="always" type="BinaryBlob">
        <column name="Version" not-null="false" />
    </version>
<!-- ... the rest -->
```

**EDIT**

But this change introduced me to another problem: `SqlServer` doesn't update the `Version` column... it always stays null.